# Проверка формы в Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter, bootstrap, javascript

Кто-нибудь реализовывал такое? Проверка формы "вшита" в bootstrap, только нигде не могу найти документацию как ей пользоваться. Нашел только, если input дать required="", то поле становится обязательным. Для остальных типов проверки не могу найти документации.
Подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атрибут `required` входит в спецификацию `HTML5` [`constraint validation API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation). `Bootstrap` тут ни при чем. Почитайте спецификацию и все станет понятно.